# Generalization of Borsuk-Ulam for arbitrary rotations

Tags: algebraic-topology, rotations, spheres

Recently, someone asked me the following question:

> Let $f:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^1$ be a continuous function and $g:S^1 \times [0,2\pi) \to S^1, g(x,\varphi) = x \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\varphi}$ be the rotation of $x$ on the unit circle by $\varphi$ degrees (we identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$). Is it possible to find an $x \in S^1$ such that $f(x)=f(g(x,\varphi))$ for a fixed $\varphi \in [0,2\pi)$? If not, can we restrict $f$ to a certain property such that this equation holds?

If we set $\varphi=\pi$, we have Borsuk-Ulam. I am sure that the statement is not true for arbitrary $\varphi$, but cannot think of an example. I am therefore more interested in knowing if one can restrict the "continuous function" condition a bit more so that the statement holds.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $\varphi\in (\pi, 2\pi)$ then you can take $f$ to be constant $1$ on half circle, and goes down to $0$ over the rest. Although I'm not exactly sure what kind of condition would prevent that. We already have a very strong situation here: continuous function from a compact space.

Comment: You meant $\varphi$ *radians*, almost certainly, given the $\times[0,2\pi)$ factor

Comment: Also do you mean: fix *first* a $\varphi$, then is it true for all continuous $f$ that $f(x)=fg(x,\varphi)$ for at least one $x$?

Comment: The ptoof of Borsak Ulam for dimension $1$ crucially relies on $x\mapsto-x$ being an involution. Without that symmetry, it feels harder to prove, yet also the result feels "obvious" to me

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? Your approach works! More precisely: suppose that $f$ is such that for any $x \in S^1$, $f(e^{i\varphi}x)\neq f(x)$. Then let $g(x)=f(e^{i\varphi}x)-f(x)$, it’s a continuous function on the circle and it doesn’t vanish, so it has a constant sign (wlog $g>0$). Thus $\int_{S^1}{g} >0$. But as you noticed, $\int_{S^1}{f(x)dx}=\int_{S^1}{f(e^{i\varphi}x)dx}$, which yields the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can actually show, that this holds for every continuous function $g:S^1 \to S^1$.

Let $h(x):=f(x)-f(g(x))$. So we are looking for $h(x)=0$.

Now let $x_{\text{max}}\in S^1$ s.t. $\forall x\in S^1 : f(x_{\text{max}}) \geq f(x)$

and $x_{\text{min}}\in S^1$ s.t. $\forall x\in S^1 : f(x_{\text{min}}) \leq f(x)$

But then $h(x_{\text{max}}) \geq 0$ and $h(x_{\text{min}}) \leq 0$.

If one is equal to $0$, we found a solution, if not, the intermediate value theorem states, that there must be at least one solution for $h(x)=0$ for every path between $x_{\text{max}}$ and $x_{\text{min}}$.

Comment: We can replace $S^1$ by any compact and connected topological space for this proof to go through (with minor rewording to avoid talking about paths). However, one should keep in mind that this relies heavily on $f$ being real-valued as it exploits the ordering on $\Bbb{R}$. So, in this sense, it’s not a true generalization of Borsuk-Ulam.

Comment: Nice proof! But it is  not the classic IVT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) what you need here. It is the fact that each continuous image of  a  connected space is connected plus the fact that that the connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ are the intervals.

Comment: @PaulFrost it is just a very simple step to map a path to a real interval, there is not really a difference, so I think it is fair to say, that this is the IVT.